# glassfish - connection with mysql crashes

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I have an JSF 2.0 application deployed on glassfish 3.1.7 with JDK 7. It's working with MySQL database. For database operations I use entities and JPA controller classes generated by NetBeans.
I used it for other applications working with PostgreSQL - no problems.

My application is being used quite often during the day between 8 am and 4 pm. Everything works perfectly. But, the next day when someone tries to use my application (perform read data from db so to say), my app crashes.

I tried to install MySQL on different mashine and reconfigure connection pool to new database, but everything is the same. I also tried to add TcpKeepAlive=true property to connection pool, but with no success.

Please help me. I completely don't know what to do. Tried to do some google work, but with no success either.

Here are the logs:

```
|2012-09-20T08:09:41.213+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=115;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error Rendering View[/system/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /system/index.xhtml @96,131 value="#{indexBean.documentNr}": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to the nested exception for more details.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:67)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:185)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to the nested exception for more details.

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CacheImpl.evictAll(CacheImpl.java:177)
at jpa.DokumentJpaController.getEntityManager(DokumentJpaController.java:35)
at jpa.DokumentJpaController.findAndSortAllDocuments(DokumentJpaController.java:264)
at web.IndexBean.generateDocumentNr(IndexBean.java:650)
at web.IndexBean.getDocumentNr(IndexBean.java:240)
at web.IndexBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getDocumentNr(IndexBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 59 more
```

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to the nested exception for more details.

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.errorRetrieveDbMetadataThroughJDBCConnection(DatabaseException.java:361)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:602)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
... 78 more
```

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor454.newInstance(Unknown Source)

```
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1205)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1197)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3061)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3056)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.getMetaData(ConnectionHolder.java:345)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.getMetaData(ConnectionWrapper40.java:114)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:589)
... 80 more
```

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 30 886 849 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3102)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:931)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:607)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
at jpa.DokumentJpaController.findAndSortAllDocuments(DokumentJpaController.java:267)
... 74 more
```

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3002)
... 106 more
```

Thanks in advance.
**EDIT:** I forgot to mention: firstly, the MySQL stood on some other mashine. Now it's working on local mashine where glassfish is installed. The same errors every morning.

Comment: Sorry for bad logs formatting. I'm new here and have some problems with formatting :)

Comment: So you got rid of this error after updating JDBC driver. I have similar problem. What driver are you using now?

Comment: I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.18. And everything seems to be perfect. For now ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the connection is being timed out or closed, but there is no way to tell if it is because of a database configuration setting, network firewall or server connection pool setting.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24936/tuning-glassfish.htm#abehq has information on tuning the connection pool settings in the glassfish server.  Specifically you might want to try changing the Idle Timeout values so that connections in the pool are closed and then reobtained.  This will prevent the db/network from timing them out and having them continue to sit in the server's pool despite being unusable.

If this problem is issolated only to mysql, you will need to check the MySQL docs for settings that might be causing the connections to be closed if idle for a certain period. There are a few posts on stackoverflow dealing with the same that might help.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that upgrading jdbc driver to newer version worked. +1 for the link - It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a webapp try to run it on different browsers and check your outputs. I faced the same issue on Opera and not on chrome i.e. It looks like a security issue related settings.

Sorry for my english